# How to select the average value from 3 matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am new to MATLAB and I need help. I have 3 matrices (`A`, `B`, and `C`) and I want to create a new matrix `average_ABC` that contains average values.

```
A = [ 0.3   0.5   0.9
     0.14  0.36   0.1
      0.9   0.5  0.14]

B = [ 0.8   0.9  0.14
      0.1  0.25   0.4
      0.8  0.14  0.25]

C = [0.25   0.3  0.47
     0.12   0.3   0.2
     0.14  0.56   0.9]
```

The resulting matrix will be

```
average_matrix = [ 0.3   0.5  0.47
                  0.12  0.25   0.2
                   0.8   0.5  0.25]
```

Please, any suggestion, how can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

You can first concatenate your matrices along the third dimension (using [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)) and then compute whatever you want using the [`dim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html#inputarg_dim) parameter that is available for most functions to specify that you want to perform that operation along the third dimension.

Also you've stated that you want the average ([`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html)), but based on your example you actually want the [`median`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html). Either way, we can compute them using this method.

```
data = cat(3, A, B, C);

% Compute the mean
mean(data, 3)

%     0.45      0.56667      0.50333
%     0.12      0.30333      0.23333
%  0.61333          0.4         0.43

% Compute the median (which seems to be what you actually want)
median(data, 3)

%      0.3          0.5         0.47
%     0.12          0.3          0.2
%      0.8          0.5         0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
average_matrix=(A+B+C)/3.;
```

Comment: No, dosent' the solution

Comment: 'cos it's `./3` not `/3.`.

Comment: As I understand you don't want an average you want a median.

Comment: @MatthiasW. That distinction doesn't matter with scalars.  I'd imagine the trailing `.` is from other languages that do not default to doubles as Matlab does.